# What happens if the runner choses to play [Magnum Opus] twice?

Tags: android-netrunner

Is there any benefit to installing the same card twice? Particularly a card like [Magnum Opus](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01044)? (I understand the point for most hardware and the like, but what about ice breakers and magnum opus)

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "playing" in this case. Do you mean having multiple Magnum Opuses installed? There is no benefit to installing more than one, as each Magnum Opus must be activated individually and all do the same thing: giving you 2 credits for spending 1 click. Putting multiple copies of MO in your deck, however, increases the likelihood that you will draw it during the game, or draw it again if one was lost due to damage

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer provided by @user30903 in the comments is correct, and I believe your question effectively clarifies what you mean by "playing" as you also reference icebreakers. There is no benefit in installing Magnum Opus twice at the same time: the effects do not stack, and in fact it is detrimental due to the memory usage. The same is true of each individual icebreaker - they do not stack so there is no additional benefit to having two identical ones in play at once.

There is a benefit to having multiple copies in your deck, to raise the chances of drawing it at a useful time.

Similarly there may be benefits to installing it twice during the course of a game, for example if the first copy if destroyed somehow, but not at the same time.

The only (niche) case where I can think it might be useful to install M.Opus or an icebreaker when you already have it in play would be if you were over the hand limit, desperate not to discard any hand cards, and worried that your original copy was going to be destroyed. Then there might be a reason to install a copy, but it is likely to be an expensive solution.

Edit: Thanks to the comments for pointing out several counter-examples of icebreakers where you would want several copies of the same card installed. In general you wouldn't, but there are exceptions. My answer holds true for M.Opus.

Comment: "The same is true of each individual icebreaker - they do not stack so there is no additional benefit to having two identical ones in play at once." Atman is sulking in the corner.

Comment: Hah! That is an excellent counter-example... I'm going to leave my answer as-is because I think Atman copies with different strengths are almost like different cards, but you're completely right, that is a definite reason for playing multiple copies of the same card at the same time.

Comment: Mongoose too. :)

Comment: There are a few others, too: spike, shiv, crowbar, Cerberus, Cyber-Cypher, Faerie, Caissas, Overmind, Chameleon. The point is, it's probably worth saying something like "most individual Icebreakers", since there are so many counter-examples.

The broader point is that many installed cards have paid abilities with no limitations on how many times you can pay for them, and for those cards one would only very rarely want a duplicate installed.

Comment: and, upvoted. :)